# Only Returning 1 Item

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone help me as i'm new to php?

I'm running a movie site that using smarty template engine and what i'm trying to do is return and display all categories foreach movie  but what happens is it displays the same category 'Comedy' for all movies when i use this

The functions

```
public function getByPerma($perma, $lang=null){
    $perma = mysql_real_escape_string($perma);
    $movie = array();
    $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE perma='$perma'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)>0){
        $movie = $this->formatMovieData(mysql_fetch_assoc($e), $lang);
    }
    return $movie;
}

public function getMovieCategoryDetails($movieid,$lang=null){
    $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
    $e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movie_tags WHERE id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM movie_tags_join WHERE movie_id=$movieid)") or die(mysql_error());
    $tags = array();
    if (mysql_num_rows($e)){
        while($s = mysql_fetch_array($e)){
            $s['tag'] = json_decode($s['tag'],true);
            if ($lang){
                $s['tag'] = $s['tag'][$lang];
            }

            $tags[$s['id']] = $s;
        }
    }
    return $tags;
}
```

Called the function

```
$movies = $movie->getByPerma($perma,$language);
if (empty($movies)) {
    $movies = '';
} else {

    $tags = $movie->getMovieCategoryDetails($movies['id'],$language);
    if (!count($tags)){
        $smarty->assign("tags","");
    } else {
        $smarty->assign("tags",$tags);
    }
}
```

And displaying the categories

```
{foreach from=$tags key=id item=val name=tags}
    {$val.tag}
{/foreach}
```

I hope someone can help?

Comment: @JakeGould They're obviously part of the same application, but different problems with it.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: you should loop through the result in `getByPerma` as you did in the second function

Comment: Can you add some sample data from the tables?

Comment: @ JakeGould `= $movie` is where the function is coming from `movie.class`

Comment: @bansi Why do you think `formatMovieData` expects `$movieid`?

Comment: @Barmar sry, wrong comment deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your getByPerma() only return 1 movie info, when add item to array, [] is missing:

```
$movie = $this->formatMovieData(mysql_fetch_assoc($e), $lang);
-->
$movie[] = $this->formatMovieData(mysql_fetch_assoc($e), $lang);
```